# How to find the subimage in a large image using python cv2

Tags: python, opencv

[sample - 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQLBZ.png)

[sample - 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jo4Zl.jpg)

I have a image with sub-images inside how to find the sub-images in a main image without template method and using python code or is there any software to find the sub-image.

The sample -2   image it have 1 sub-image in it how to find it.

```
import cv2

# Load the image
image = cv2.imread("img_2.jpg")

# Define the callback function for the threshold slider
def threshold_callback(threshold):
    # Perform Canny edge detection
    edges = cv2.Canny(image, threshold, threshold*2)
    # Display the edges
    cv2.imshow("Edges", edges)

# Create a window to display the original image
cv2.namedWindow("Original", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow("Original", image)

# Create a trackbar for adjusting the threshold
cv2.createTrackbar("Threshold", "Original", 0, 255, threshold_callback)

# Wait for the user to press a key
cv2.waitKey(0)

# Close all windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

i try this but it not working.

Comment: which one of the subimages do you want to find?

Comment: i have added new image

Comment: explain "find". do you have a specific picture you need to find in another picture, or do you generally want to decompose mosaics and picture-in-picture situations? -- please take the [tour] and review [ask].

Comment: Hi @ChristophRackwitz in the sample - 2 image it has inline picture I want to select that picture for example I want to select that sky image from bird image i know we can use template but i want to get without using template image

Comment: in the general case, that will require AI. the inset picture in the PiP situation can look arbitrarily indistinguishable from the background image, at least on a low level.